# First n elements of row in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to implement a k-nearest neighbour classifier in Python, and so I want to calculate the Euclidean distance. I have a dataset that I have converted into a big numpy array

```
[[  0.   0.   4. ...,   1.   0.   1.]
 [  0.   0.   5. ...,   0.   0.   1.]
 [  0.   0.  14. ...,  16.   9.   1.]
 ..., 
 [  0.   0.   3. ...,   2.   0.   3.]
 [  0.   1.   7. ...,   0.   0.   3.]
 [  0.   2.  10. ...,   0.   0.   3.]]
```

where the last element of each row indicates the class. So when calculating the Euclidean distance, I obviously don't want to include the last element. I thought I could do the following

```
for row in dataset:
    distance = euclidean_distance(vector, row[:dataset.shape[1] - 1])
```

but that still includes the last element

```
print row
>>> [[  0.   0.   4. ...,   1.   0.   1.]]
print row[:dataset.shape[1] - 1]
>>> [[  0.   0.   4. ...,   1.   0.   1.]]
```

as you can see both are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subset the data using numpy slicing.  If you find yourself iterating over a numpy array, stop and try to find a method that takes advantage of the vectorized nature of numpy operations.

Assuming your array is called `arr`:

```
data_points = arr[:,:-1]
classes = arr[:,-1]
```

---

#### For distance to vector calculations:

To find the distance between a 1d array and all of the rows of a 2d array, you can use to following.  It assumes the 1d array is `v` and the 2d array is `arr`.

```
dist = np.power(arr - v, 2).sum(axis=1)
```

`dist` will be a 1d array of distances.

---

#### For pairwise calculations:

The following function takes a 2d array of numbers and returns the upper-diagonal matrix of pair-wise distances using the given L-x distance measurement (the Euclidean distance measure is the L=2 metric).

```
def pairwise_distance(arr, L=2):
    d = arr.shape[0]
    out = np.zeros(d)
    for f in range(1, d):
        out[:-f].ravel()[f::d+1] = np.power(arr[:-f]-arr[f:], L).sum(axis=1)
    return np.power(out, 1.0/L)
```

Comment: My idea was to create a `Counter` with the index of each row as a key and the Euclidean distance as a value, and then get the `k` indices with the lowest distance and return these. How could I do this without iterating over the dataset / is there a better way than doing this with a `Counter`?

Comment: I added a method for calculating the pairwise distances.  Please remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I didn't ask that though, I asked how I could calculate this for each row in a numpy array without iterating over it since you said you shouldn't iterate over a numpy array. 

P.S. you can simply use `np.linalg.norm(a - b)` where `a` and `b` are numpy arrays to calculate the Euclidean distance.

Comment: Ok, I reread your question.  Yup I totally missed what you were asking.  I think I have answered it now.